# What errors are outputted to http.Server's ErrorLog struct field?

Tags: go, http.server

I'm trying to understand the purpose of an `ErrorLog` struct field in `http.Server` struct. By its name I suspect that those are some kind of errors, but which ones?

What would trigger errors being outputted there? Broken network? Too large http requests?

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    _ = &http.Server{
        ErrorLog: log.Default(), // what errors are outputted here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server) provides an overview of how the field is used:

```golang
    // ErrorLog specifies an optional logger for errors accepting
    // connections, unexpected behavior from handlers, and
    // underlying FileSystem errors.
    // If nil, logging is done via the log package's standard logger.
    ErrorLog *log.Logger // Go 1.3
```

In practice, the field is accessed in the `*http.Server`'s `logf` method. You can check where that method is called. In short (not exhaustive):

- on panics serving HTTP requests (`conn`'s `serve(ctx context.Context)`)
- on TLS handshake errors
- on the server's `Serve(l net.Listener) error` errors
- on writing non-empty data to the response, if the connection was [hijacked](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_Hijacker)
- if the `Content-Length` is invalid
- if you call `WriteHeader(code int)` on the same response more than once
- if `Content-Length` and non-`identity` `Transfer-Encoding` headers are used together

Answer (score 0):

```
 type serverErrorLogWriter struct{}
    
    func (*serverErrorLogWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
        m := string(p)
        if strings.HasPrefix(m, "http: TLS handshake error") && strings.HasSuffix(m, ": EOF\n") {
            // handle EOF error
        } else {
            // handle other errors
        }
        return len(p), nil
    }
    
    func newServerErrorLog() *log.Logger {
        return log.New(&serverErrorLogWriter{}, "", 0)
    }
```

And then

```
ErrorLog:          log.New(&serverErrorLogWriter{}, "", 0)
```

Comment: Hi, can you comment on what problem does your code solve?

Comment: This is the custom error logger and you can log your http errors here or do filter etc.